# How do I make QAbstractSpinBox auto-repeat the up/down buttons?

Tags: qt

I've subclassed Qt QAbstractSpinBox to create ComplexSpinBox that handles complex numbers.

To do this, I'm overriding keyPressEvent(), mousePressEvent(), and wheelEvent() and if the keyboard Ctrl modifier is active then the imaginary portion of the complex number is incremented or decremented.  Otherwise the real portion is updated.  (Also including a custom validator for complex numbers.)

All is cool except that holding the up and down arrow buttons down doesn't make them repeat.

What am I leaving out?

Comment: QAbstractSpinBox also provide a virtual function stepEnabled() to determine whether stepping up/down is allowed at any point. This function returns a bitset of StepEnabled.

Answer (score 0):

Well, one, if not *the* way to do this is to add

```
private:
   QTimer *timer;
```

in the definition and create it in the constructor:

```
  timer = new QTimer(this);
  connect (timer, &QTimer::timeout,
       [=]() {
         // do your thing
       });
```

Then somewhere in the mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *mouseEvent) method

```
timer->start (100);
```

For reasons that aren't clear to me, mouseReleaseEvent() doesn't get triggered in this environment so you have to use an event filter.  Back in the definition, you'll need:

```
protected:
    bool eventFilter(QObject *object, QEvent *event);
```

and the method

```
bool ComplexSpinBox::eventFilter(QObject *object, QEvent *event)
{
  if (object == this && event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonRelease) {
   
    timer->stop ();
  }
  return false;
}
```